# How to access collections within NameValueCollection returned by HttpUtility.ParseQueryString?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, query-string, uri

Using C#, .net 4.0

I'm using HttpUtility.ParseQueryString to parse a mailto URI, as such:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
NameValueCollection mailTo = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(mailToUri.OriginalString.Split('?')[1]);
message.Subject = mailTo["subject"];
```

The URI can have multiple "to" parameters, such as:

```
mailto://?to=address1@email.com&to=address2@email.com&to=address3@email.com&subject=test&body=this%20should%20be%20the%20body"
```

When stepping through the code I can see ParseQueryString creates the mailTo["to"] NameValueCollection that contains a single "to" key with multiple values, which appears to be an object of type System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.NameObjectEntry

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. I haven't been able to figure out how to iterate over this collection and get each individual value. I'd be looking for something like this, which obviously doesn't work:

```
        foreach (String address in mailTo["to"])
        {
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(address));
        }
```

Additionally, if you know a better way to go from mailto URI to SMTP message I'm all eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the value part of the NameValueCollection is a string.  So for the "to" key it would be a comma delimited string of email addresses.

```
string s = "to=address1@email.com&to=address2@email.com&to=address3@email.com&subject=test";
var items = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(s);

foreach(string email in items["to"].Split(','))
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(email);
}
```

results in the following

```
address1@email.com
address2@email.com
address3@email.com
```

Comment: Of course, so simple. Viewing the item["to"] in debug breaks out the values into a collection rather than showing the single comma delimited value, leading me down all the wrong paths. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question without offering an alternative solution, try this:

```
     foreach (var value in mailTo.GetValues("to"))
     {
        Debug.WriteLine(value);
     }
```

Comment: So much better because you don't have to worry about any of the original values containing a comma.

Answer (score 0):

The mailTo["to"] is simply a string that contains the comma-separated addresses which you can split and parse like this:

```
    foreach (var address in mailTo["to"].Split(','))
    {
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(address));
    }
```